# Thymeleaf plugin installation error in STS 4

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, thymeleaf, spring-tool-suite

I am not able to download thymeleaf plugin in my STS for Spring Boot 5 project

Trying to install thymeleaf plugin for the STS 4 from Help -> Install New Software -> Add -> Name : thymeleaf, location: https://www.thymeleaf.org/eclipse-plugin-update-site/.

After some time gettting this :

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd3bl.png)

Comment: The site works fine on Eclipse 2023-09. Are you saying the progress bar continues to run?

Comment: Please temporarily disable the option _Contact all update sites during install to find required software_ to check whether the Thymeleaf update site is the problem or an update site in the preferences _Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ is slow and should be better disabled.

Comment: @greg-449 No. After some time the progress bar stops and an error is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I looked into this github reference #104  [link](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-eclipse-plugin/issues/104#issuecomment-838063930). I downloaded the zip file and added it. The installation was successful.