# Unable to install Thymeleaf plugin to the Spring Tool Suite-4-4.20.1

Tags: eclipse-plugin, thymeleaf, spring-tool-suite, spring-thymeleaf

I am unable to install Thymeleaf plugin to the STS. The screenshot related to the error is attached. I tried installing it from Eclipse Marketplace. Please guide me to get it installed.

I wanted to create an HTML page under templates for one of my maven project using "right-click on templates >> New >> Other >> searched for HTML", but didn't found any.

I basically want to create the frontend for my project using HTML. If there is any other way out then please guide me with that.

[image]

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77358177/6505250 ?